# Laravel: $errors->first() doesn't show error. How to make it work?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to show validation errors below each form element. I used {{ $errors->first('control1') }} but, it does not show the validation errors. 
No clue about how to get around with this.

Below is my view code snippet.

```
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="control1" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-left">{{ __('Number of control1') }}</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control col-md-8" id="control1" name="control1" value="{{ old('control1', 2) }}" required minvalue="1" />

                            @if ($errors->has('control1'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('control1') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                    </div>
```

in controller action, thebelow validation is written.

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'control1' => 'required|min:1', 
        ]);
```

Comment: Can you show your full controller code? Because I see now you edited to match the field name

Comment: it is validating the $request variables as shown above and then, assigning it to the model attribute to save.

Comment: make sure that you use the correct route. Because if you use it like you show there is nothing wrong. So I am not even sure if you are reaching this line for the validator, try debugging that.

Comment: I checked. The code is working but, the error is not shown in the html.

Comment: and in the view within your check if the `$errors->has('control1')` and you put any text will it be print out?

Answer (score 0):

You are validating a field named `sprints`. So change your validator array to match that, from this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'sprints' => 'required|min:1', 
]);
```

to this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'control1' => 'required|min:1', 
]);
```

And depending on your laravel version you can even simplify it like this:

```
$request->validate([
    'control1' => 'required|min:1', 
]);
```

Then in your view write this:

```
@error('control1')
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
@enderror
```

Comment: The view change did not show the validation error. 
How the $message will get the error message?

Comment: Laravel magic, read more in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors).

Comment: ```
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
{{ $error }}
@endforeach
```
shows the error message but not $error->first('control1')

Comment: I really don't know what else to say.. Print the key as well, to make sure that you are looking for the correct one.
`@foreach($errors->all() as $key => $error) {{ $key . ' - ' . $error }} @endforeach`
Make sure you use a laravel version which does not by any chance contains an error on that part which was fixed in a later version.

Comment: This was a CSS error. A bug in bootstrap4 (beta bug). 

Bug can be tracked here.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23454